# Transform PDF to FixedDocument

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, fixeddocument, pdfrenderer

My goal is to be able to display PDF documents using `DocumentViewer` (WPF control). `DocumentViewer` is able to display only `FixedDocumnets`. Is there any way to transform PDF to `FixedDocument`. 
Thank you for answers

Answer (score 2):

Read this MSDN discussion:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsxps/thread/1917fede-bf5c-4c66-92cd-e97cfa0206cc

there are some alternatives discussed (involving Ghostscript and some commercial solutions).